# sklearn.cluster.Kmeans.cluster_centers_ are in the wrong order

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` as a way to take an array of pixels, cluster it, replace every pixel with a centroid and, thus, reduce the number of colors in an image.

[image: Postmodernism]

I get really weird results:

[image: Results]

It seems like `Kmeans.cluster_centers_` is just a collection of cluster centroids in no particular order and the centroid of a particular cluster cannot be accessed with `Kmeans.cluster_centers_[c]`. Is there another way to access it?

Comment: In images, the first dimension is the y coordinate (rows, so to speak). KMeans returns (x, y) pairs.

Comment: @MaxNoe But I am passing a one-dimensional array of pixels to KMeans (`n` by `3` array, where `3` is RGB)

Comment: You cluster the image in 1d? And what are the values? `[R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2, ...]`?

Comment: No. It's 1d in terms of pixels. In terms of integers it's 2d: `[[R1, G1, B1], [R2, G2, B2], ..]`. Sorry for misleading phrasing.